# Trying to sort on two fields first is second criteria

Tags: sort

I'm trying to sort on multiple columns a file with GNU sort.

The format of the source file tmp/file.txt is :

```
03A12345679   2014-09-30-00.00.01.00
```

- "03" => first column
- "A" => field separator
- "12345679   " => second column
- "2014-09-30-00.00.01.00" => other column (not sorted)

I've tried this command :

```
sort --field-separator="A" -k2,11 -k1,2 tmp/file.txt > tmp/file_out.txt
```

With :

- `--field-separator="A"` => field separator is "A"
- `-k2,11` => the second column is the first sort ("12345679   ")
- `-k1,2` => the first column is the second sort ("03")

But in the result the sort is not correct (the "03" is before the "01" and "02" lines) :

```
03A12345679   2014-09-30-00.00.01.000000-0000
01A12345679   12345679  132132155VDVLDLV
02A12345679   FONDSEURO   000012664,120000000M
02A12345679   FR09999956570000009999,999990000F
01A12345680   472958519598601200000000047295824
02A12345680   122121EUR     0000099999,370000000M
```

I want to have this result :

```
01A12345679   12345679  132132155VDVLDLV
02A12345679   FONDSEURO   000012664,120000000M
02A12345679   FR09999956570000009999,999990000F
03A12345679   2014-09-30-00.00.01.000000-0000
01A12345680   472958519598601200000000047295824
02A12345680   122121EUR     0000099999,370000000M
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: Some of these lines look like French bank information. You might want to mask it a little.

Comment: It's test data. Not real data. Only ISIN code are real but everything else it random data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up field positions and character positions. There is no need to split on `A`; with GNU sort, you can sort on a range of characters within the first space-delimited field:

```
$ sort -k1.4,1.11 -k1.1,1.2 file
01A12345679   12345679  132132155VDVLDLV
02A12345679   FONDSEURO   000012664,120000000M
02A12345679   FR09999956570000009999,999990000F
03A12345679   2014-09-30-00.00.01.000000-0000
01A12345680   472958519598601200000000047295824
02A12345680   122121EUR     0000099999,370000000M
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `-g` (compare according to general numerical value) to sort:

```
sort --field-separator="A" -g -k2,11 -k1,2 tmp/file.txt > tmp/file_out.txt
```